# Stock prediction using MLP(Multi Layer Perceptron).

Tags: neural-network, time-series, prediction, stock

Me and some classmates are enrolled on a discipline of artificial intelligence and we are trying to replicate the result of the article "Stock price prediction using genetic algorithms and evolution strategies". The article solves the binary classification problem of saying whether a stock is gonna increase or decrease the next day. We got some bad results, the algorithm seems to be leading to only one result, it eiher outputs increasing or decreasing to every input. We tried a MLP with 6 input neurons, one hidden neuron and one output neuron, using a genetic algorithm to set the input weights. We used a data set of ten years from 2006 to 2016 for training with the attributes: open value, high value, low value, volume, close, adjusted close. Does anyone have an idea of what we could do differently to get better results? And is there something we're doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view is problem in hidden units count. You use only one hidden neuron and this is maybe not enough to Stock prediction. Try add more hidden units.